# Hyper-v server 2016 doesn't restart VM (just stop)

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v-server-2016, reboot

just finished provisioning a new hpe dl380g9 server with hyperv server 2016. Installed it on microsd (yes, it is supported by HPE). All recommended updates installed.

Everything seemed smooth but now, provisioning VMs I have a major trouble. Being them either Linux or Windows VM, if I try to restart a VM, what I got MOSTLY is just a Stop. Now and then the VM actually restarts.

I've tried to restart the entire server but issue is still here!

Issuing several

> stop-VM; start-VM

seem to work.

**I post here some system settings:**

hyper-v server is on microsd

VM are in 2 arrays each one managed by a raid controller.

when a VM is created in array 1 I (think to) put all required files (from definitions to paging) into such an array, nothing is kept on the sd.

the only actual change to hyper-v server (other than HPE drivers installed by windows at automatically at install time) is that I've disabled the paging file.

I've tested a number of VM (linux, windows) all gen2, with windows defender either ON or OFF on the host.

all VM have dynamic vhdx and dynamic memory.

Honestly I don't even know from where to start sorting this out.

Any hint? Thank you!

Comment: TBH, disabling the pagefile is a non-standard configuration. As a first step, try enabling the pagefile and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Have a look at the event log; that's always the first troubleshooting step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was an issue with the default location of vVMs smart paging file. Keeping it at default suggested location solved. Also reinstalled controller drivers just in case...